# How to get Twilio call status in Laravel?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have a Laravel app where I have some logic and I'm using Twilio to make the phone call but I  want to make when the user missed the phone call after the user will get the SMS and for that, I need to know the call status but how do I get the call status in Laravel. If anybody can help me please feel free to respond.

```php
public function initiateCall(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate form input
        $this->validate($request, [
            'phone_number' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        try {
            //Lookup phone number to make sure it is valid before initiating call
            $phone_number = $this->client->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers($request->phone_number)->fetch();

            // If phone number is valid and exists
            if ($phone_number) {
                // Initiate call and record call
                $call = $this->client->account->calls->create(
                    $request->phone_number, // Destination phone number
                    $this->from, // Valid Twilio phone number
                    array(
                        "record" => True,
                        "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
                    )
                );

                if ($call) {
                    echo 'Call initiated successfully';
                } else {
                    echo 'Call failed!';
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        } catch (RestException $rest) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $rest->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource

You can simply use the `statusCallback` with `statusCallbackMethod`. It will return the post variables on your mentioned URL. There you can fetch your required variables.

Comment: Hi, I have already used but the live URL not giving me any data after the phone call

https://prnt.sc/qZJrNz7oIxi8

Comment: print the request, by writing each request in log file. Then check what you are getting. Also make the log file writeable permission

Comment: You need to point that statusCallback URL at your own application. If you need to test while developing locally, you can check out [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) as a way to create a public URL for your local machine development.

Comment: I have the live URL which is valid and I also try to get the response using postman or Thunder Client but not the response

Answer (score 0):

In the else section of the code when the code echo 'Call failed!'

```
else {
   echo 'Call failed!';
}
```

you can create or call a function here to send a SMS to user after failed call & also you can set a counter variable here that changes the variable's value to indicate that call is failed.

Comment: here is the else when the number is not valid and not initiated the call I need the response when after initiated the call status such as no-answer, busy, completed, answer